# OpenCV and Pupil size proof

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to find a white paper, book, or other publication measuring pupil size with OpenCV but am coming up empty.  Any one know of anyone doing this?

Thanks,
rd42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it if anyone is curious.

[Paper on pupillometry](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://bibliotecadigital.sbc.org.br/download.php?paper=1482&rct=j&q=A%20prototype%20of%20the%20system%20was%20developed%20using%20a%20microcomputer%20Athlon%201.5GHz%20with%201GB%20RAM,%20running%20Linux.%20The%20programs%20was%20developed%20in%20C%2b%2b,%20using%20OpenCV%20for%20most%20of%20the%20computer%20vision%20routines.%20The%20prototype%20is%20able%20to%20capture%208%20bit%20grey%20level%20images%20of%20640%C3%97480%20pixels%20of%20a%20NTSC%20video%20camera.&ei=taRJTqGUJYeitgeMkpjiBQ&usg=AFQjCNHLWH75M0Gl1rYFEeSTsYXnVnEZ0A&sig2=HfABaA3gOz46jRI0BGeBdg&cad=rja://)

Comment: website not loading. Do you mind sharing it here(if legal)?